# Which is the best way to store sensitive credentials in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I started learning Node.js a few days ago, and I'm facing a question about the credentials of the database and the [Gmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) connection (the last is needed for `nodemailer`).

I essentially created a file like this:

```
const config = {
    development: {
        url: '127.0.0.1',

        database: {
            host: 'mongodb://localhost',
            port: '27017',
            db: 'foo'
        },

        gmail: {
            username: 'foo@gmail.com',
            password: 'foo',
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '3000'
        }
    },

    production:{
        url: 'https://my.site.com',

        database: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '27017',
            db: 'foo'
        },
        gmail: {
            username: 'foo@gmail.com',
            password: 'foo',
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '3000'
        }
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I do not like to enter this information into the application, so after some research I found this library: [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). This library stores the information inside the *[process.env](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processenv)* property, but the substance is the same... Why should I prefer a solution like `dotenv` against my `config` module?

What do you suggest?

Comment: you config module is visible to all as dotenv is different for each environment.For e.g development environment .env has  entry specific to development server

Comment: @MonicaGarud so essentially you suggest to use `dotenv` instead of a javascript configuration?

Comment: yes use dotenv instead of a javascript configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used the *dotenv* package, because it creates a file and saves it into your process, whereas *config.js* will not save in the process.

But why do I have to save in the process?

The first thing: credentials will never be pushed to [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) or any other version control system. If we don't push this file to Git, and if I clone it after some later time, the program will crash. But in this case, if I use the *Process.env* property, the program will not crash.

And second, if we have big team, we can also put extra security on the process file and but put extra security on the JavaScript file, because the developing team should have access to these file for editing and other stuff.

This is useful for more information:
*[Managing Configurations in Node.js applications with dotenv and convict](https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/managing-configurations-in-node-js-apps-with-dotenv-and-convict-d74070d37373)*

Answer (score 6):

I absolutely recommend *dotenv*, and this is what it was created for. However, I would specifically recommend to use the *dotenv-safe* npm package. That offers upgraded features compared to *dotenv*.

Since you are not going to push your `.env.xy` files to version management, such as Git, with all the sensitive data in it, you can quickly get confused about what variables should you be putting into your environment files, especially if you are working in teams.

Let’s say Adam creates a new environment variable, uses it in his code and pushes his code. Since the environment files are in file *.gitignore*, you only get to notice that Adam introduced a new environment variable when your code *tries to use the variable* and breaks. With *dotenv-safe* however, you push your `.env.example` file with valid keys, but with dummy values, for example, `MY_API_KEY=somerandomgibberish` to Git, while your real value would be `MY_API_KEY=aaf347xkhskallmtopsecret` in your `.env.production` file.

Dotenv-safe doesn’t allow running your application if your real *.env* file, in this case `.env.production`, has any mismatching keys compared to file `.env.example` which you just pulled from Git. This way, you discover that Adam added his new environment variable when *starting your app*.

This way, no unexpected behaviour will come up once your application has all the variables it has predefined in `.env.example`, protecting you from a lot of headache and thousands of unnecessary redeploys in the long run. :)

Comment: My question to you would be, how do I provision this .env.production to the app during production using a CI tool, since I can't commit the file, how do I hook it back during the automatic deployment?

Comment: Sorry, just recognized this comment. You must have an option at the deployment provider, e.g: Heroku / Github CI to provide environment variables (see:[this link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets))